# How to fix internet disconnection between wireless adapter and access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection

The setup:

- Laptop (Acer S5-371T)
- Windows 10 (Home)
- Qualcomm Atheros (QCA61x4A) wireless adapater
- Netgear (D1500) router with ADSL connection
- Distance between router and device about 5 metres

---

> There have not been any issues in the past. The connection worked
>   very well.

However recently the connection drops/breaks after a few minutes after being connected. 
(**Other devices sharing the same wireless connection do not have connection problems.** Devices being chromecast, android phone, iphone..)

Troubleshooting finds two problems:

- Connection between your access point or router and the internet is broken
- Problem with wireless adapter or access point

[Windows Network diagnostics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N3uQ.png)

After the wireless adapter is resetted by the diagnostic program, the internet connection works again but only temporarily.

[ip config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDRQL.png)

---

I have tried these commands without a permananent fix:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Can someone suggest what I could do to fix this problem?

Comment: Model number of router, model number of wifi, Distance between you and router ....

Comment: Model number of router - D1500 (Netgear),  model number of wifi - QCA61x4A (Qualcomm Atheros), distance about 4 to 6 metres.

Comment: Model number of the computer would’ve been more useful. Have you tried updating the drivers from the manufacturer’s website?